# Is each 的 in 有的 and 好的，到时候会有人接机的 a modal particle?

Tags: grammar, particles

In next extract from a text while reserving a hotel room there are some final 的.

> 1: 请问你们旅馆有没有免费接送服务?
>   2: 有**的**。请问你们星期三几天到?
>   1: 早上六点40分到达海南国际机场。
>   2: 好**的**，到时候会有人接机**的**。先星期三见。

In the last ..example 到时候会有人接机**的** II have seen in the next grammar point that is a modal particle used preferably with 会。

https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Using_%22de%22_(modal_particle)。

But what about the simple 有**的** and 好**的**. ¿what grammar refers to this two cases?. I cannot find any.

Answer (score 1):

in 有的 and 好的, 的 is just a modal particle also.
It is Ok if you omit 的.

another example: 可以的=可以